# Has anyone used NUnitLite with any success?

Tags: unit-testing, windows-mobile, compact-framework, nunit

I've recently started work on the Compact Framework and I was wondering if anyone had some recommendations for unit testing beyond what's in VS 2008. MSTest is *ok*, but debugging the tests is a nightmare and the test runner is *so* slow.

I see that NUnitLite on codeplex is an option, but it doesn't look very active; it's also in the roadmap for NUnit 3.0, but who knows when that will come out. Has anyone had any success with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What we've done that really improves our efficiency and quality is to multi target our mobile application.  That is to say with a very little bit of creativity and a few conditional compile tags and custom project configurations it is possible to build a version of your mobile application that also runs on the desktop.

If you put all your business logic you need tested in a separate project/assembly then this layer can be very effectively tested using any of the desktop tools you are already familiar with.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. It's a shame though: the emulator is so easy to automate that it would be much better to test on the platform that the app will be deployed on.

Answer (score 0):

We use NUnitLite, although I think we did have had to add some code to it in order for it to work.

One of the problems we found is that if you are using parts of the platform that only exist in CF, then you can only run those tests in NUnitLite on an emulator or Windows Mobile device, which makes it hard to run the tests as part of an integrated build process. We got round this by added a new test attribute allowing you to disable the tests what would only run on the CF (typically these would be p/invoking out to some windows mobile only dll).